# How to create a multi select button in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to create a multi select box for food toppings.

[image]

I would like to click on the American cheese and have both in a active state but every time I click one the other :hover state is remove.

I'm using angular is that makes any different.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a CSS `.active` class. Then on `click` of your elements check if it has that class, remove it if it already does and add it otherwise. To do that you can use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass( 'active' );
});
```

```css
.btn { border: 1px solid grey; }
.btn.active { background-color: DimGrey; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn'>Extra Chesse</button>
<button class='btn'>American Chesse</button>
<button class='btn'>Swiss Chesse</button>
```